# How can I reduce timing complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Recently I migrated from java to python soI am used to lengthy codes
I wonder how can I reduce the timing complexity of the below code.

```
def main():

    n_ingri = int(input())
    ingri = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:n_ingri]
    quant = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:n_ingri]

    power_puff = 0
    count = 0

    terminate = True

    while terminate:
        for x in range(n_ingri):
            if ingri[x] <= quant[x]:
                count += 1
            else:
                break

        if count != n_ingri:
            terminate = False

        else :
            power_puff += 1 
            count = 0
            for x in range(n_ingri):
                quant[x] = quant[x] - ingri[x]

    print(power_puff)

main()
```

Comment: That depends: what exactly is the code supposed to do? The time complexity is unlikely to be very different, but the code can probably be written more idiomatically.

Comment: @chepner It looks like it's subtracting all of `ingri` from all of `quant` repeatedly, as long as all elements of `ingri` are `<=` the corresponding elements of `quant`, returning the number of multiples of `ingri` that were subtracted from `quant`.  It could do it in a single pass if it used `%` to determing the number of multiples, but whether that would be faster depends on how many iterations are needed.

Comment: @TomKarzes The question is more to get the OP to focus on what he wants to do, rather than how to translate Java-style code to Python in a rote fashion, step-by-step fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I reduce the complexity using division so you only need to iterate once.

```
def main():
    n_ingri = int(input())
    ingri = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:n_ingri]
    quant = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:n_ingri]

    divs = [quant[i] // ingri[i] for i in range(n_ingri)]
    power_puff = min(divs)
    # Update quant so the final quant result is the same (uncomment if needed)
    # quant = [quant[i] - min_div*ingri[i] for i in range(n_ingri)]

    print(power_puff)

main()
```

Notice that I comment the quant update, but you can uncomment it if you want to get the same exact quant values at the end of the main().

Comment: Answered with perfection

Comment: I tried same before you answer just what I mistaken was I use '/' instead of this and then converted it to integer from float which was increasing the complexity. Thanks again its best solution you gave to me

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes, in python3 we need to be careful with `/` and `//` for division operation